Use as few connections as possible to upload multiple files (curl)
I want to upload multiple files via a ssh connection w/ curl. My implementation at the moment is the following:

open ssh connection (ssh2_connect)
iterate over files, check if file exists on the remote sftp (curl)
if not upload file to remote sftp as *.tmp
iterate over files an rename it on the remote sftp (ssh2_sftp_rename)

Is there a better way, with as few connections as possible?

Why the upload as *.tmp first, only to rename it afterwards? Are you worried about someone/something else accessing "expected" files based on their final names, before they'd be fully uploaded or something? If the renaming isn't an actual requirement - use rsync maybe?

As above, or rsync to a staging directory, then use ssh to mv staging import ? Fewer connections, but requires that your remote site will "give" you a staging dir. Hmm. not certain how atomic the mv command is, test that it creates import/file.gz directory entry only after any copy/move processes are complete. Good luck.
